# How to free a BST that contains a char pointer?

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree, free

This is a node that im using to create a BST. How would I be able to free this tree. Below is an attempt of what I have tried but Im not too sure how to free str.

```
typedef struct tree_s tree_t;

struct tree_s 
{
    char *str;
    tree_t *left;
    tree_t *right;
};

void freeTree(tree_t *tree) {
    if (tree == NULL) 
    {
        return;
    }
    /* first delete both subtrees */
    freeTree(tree->left);
    free(tree->str);
    freeTree(tree->right);

    /* then delete the node */
    free(tree);
 }
```

Comment: How did you allocate "str" to begin with?

Comment: @selbie I malloc'd it

Comment: Once you delete the whole tree and second time when you will be adding the nodes again  you may get the error because you must not have changed the value of the `root` to **NULL**

Comment: Your code looks good to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have a postorder traversal (that is what you are doing) and `free()` the memory allocated. [ `free(str)`] In your case `free(tree->str)`;
  You have done it correctly. A more concise one

```
void preord(tree *root)
{
if(root)
{
   preord(root->left);
   preord(root->right);
   free(tree->str);
   free(tree);
}
}
```

---

**Note:** Once you know the node at which you are working currently is non-null then you can free the `char *` any time , only remember that the children must be freed before the parent.

Comment: @Qpls.: check my answer.

Comment: ill give it a try. is there anyway to know if the entire tree has been completely freed?/checking if freeing was successful

Comment: You can use valgrind or VSstudio features.